# php can't send email

Tags: php, email, send, contacts

I have been trying to send a php contact form, but it's not working at all.
my xampp use 8080 port.

I though that I have to change some configuration on php.ini or httpd.conf as well.

Please anybody help me.

Thank you.

this is the script:

```
    <?php
    $to = "tiya.vort4@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Test mail";
    $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
    $from = "someonelse@example.com";

    $headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
   'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

   if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
     echo "Mail Sent.";
   }
```

Comment: Do any errors appear? (Have you checked both your PHP error log and the mail log on the server you're using to transmit email.)

Comment: xampp is a windows based stack yes? The issue is Windows can't natively send emails, you need some extra software to do that. Of course if it's not you can totally ignore my comment! [Google results for sendmail for windows](https://www.google.com.cy/search?q=sendmail+for+windows&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=CxwiUpaXJoOotAbi7YCgAQ)

Comment: nothing error appear. it's wrote "main sent" php echo. It's meaning that nothing error. but i really dont have an idea about it

Answer (score 0):

You would have to [configure the mercury server](http://community.pmail.com/files/folders/mercur/entry44.aspx) bundled with xampp to actually deliver/relay the mails.

Comment: My mercury was stop, but i just started it. how to configure the mercury

Comment: check this tutorial out. http://kyrathaba.dcmembers.com/errata/configureMercuryMail.htm